# Is there an easy way to change directories from within one duplicate folder structure to another?

Tags: bash, directory, cd-command

On our server, we have several duplicate-ish folder structures for testing, staging, and production. Other than minor changes, the folder structure between all three are generally the same.

When I'm working on a WordPress plugin, I'm deep within the development folder structure (ex `~/dev/com/wp-content/plugins/myplugin`). I know that `~/staging/com/wp-content/plugins/myplugin` exists.

If my current working directory is `~/dev/com/wp-content/plugins/myplugin`, can I somehow easily switch to `~/staging/com/wp-content/plugins/myplugin` *without* typing the entire directory structure?

I'd like to type something like **`cdx`**`~/staging`, or even **`cdx`**`../../../../../staging` and have the command try to traverse down the new directory using my current directory path. Obviously, if the new folder doesn't contain the proper structure, it would error out.

Am I stuck typing the entire directory structure? Or is there a better way?

Comment: What shell do you use? Some shells will make what you want to do a bit easier.

Comment: I generally use bash.

Comment: In zsh, you simply do `cd dev staging`. I think I remember a question on this site where someone had posted bash code to do the same (a more elaborate version of [muru's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/168461)), but I can't find it.

Answer (score 6):

Use string substitution in `bash`:

```
$ a="~/dev/com/wp-content/plugins/myplugin"
$ echo ${a/dev/staging}
~/staging/com/wp-content/plugins/myplugin
```

So a function like:

```
cdx () 
{
    cd "${PWD/$1/$2}"
}
```

And then do `cdx dev staging` to switch from a folder in `dev` to `staging`. With some checks, you could name the function `cd`:

```
cd ()
{
    if [ $# != 2 ]
    then
        builtin cd "$@"
    else
        builtin cd "${PWD/$1/$2}"
    fi
}
```

Effect:

```
~ # cd /tmp
/tmp # cd tmp srv
/srv # cd
~ # cd -
/srv
/srv # cd tmp var
/srv #
```

This retains the usual behaviour of `cd` in all cases, except for two arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Add this function to your `.bash_profile` and typing `cdstaging` you will be able to change between any directory inside `~/dev` to the equivalent on `~/staging`.

Of course you can change the name for whatever you want. Additionally, you could create a reverse function just changing function name and `"1s@dev@staging@"` to just the opposite.

```
cdstaging ()
{
        OLDPATH=$(pwd | sed -e "1s@$HOME@~@")
        NEWPATH=$(echo $OLDPATH | sed -e "1s@dev@staging@")
        cd $NEWPATH
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In `ksh` or `zsh`:

```
cd dev staging
```